# What is the right translation for "replacement class"?

Tags: translation

I wanted to say the sentence "I have a replacement class this Saturday". I translated "replacement class" in Google translate and got 替换课程. But when I typed the full sentence on Google translate it is 替补课. So should my sentence be 这个星期六我有替换课程 or 这个星期六我有替补课 or is there any other more appropriate/colloquial way to say it?

Comment: Can you explain what a *replacement class* is in English?

Comment: Let's say a teacher couldn't come to teach on one day, so the teacher pick another extra day to teach so that he/she can replace the class.

Comment: Nounification is quite a unique feature of English. Chinese uses verbs more often.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you described is usually called 调（tiáo）课 in Chinese. I am not sure if there is a corresponding noun for replacement class in Chinese, but the sentence you had

> I have a replacement class this Saturday

can be translated to

> 我们有一节课调（tiáo）到这周六了

Answer (score 2):

in addition to what @zyy answered:

调 means making adjustments
课 means class

`调课` sometimes implicitly means that we are swapping two classes, so it is slightly different from `replacement class`.

other possible translations:

这周六我有一节课要补

这周六要补上一节课